# Ordering is not working correctly for particular group in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x

Here i'm trying change the ordering for the particular group by click and trag in List view.I have several categories and some datas for those categoies.

If I add the below code in my default.php

```
$saveOrderlistUrl= 'index.php?option=com_xxxx&task=groups.saveOrderAjax&tmpl=component';
JHtml::_('sortablelist.sortable', 'groupsList', 'adminForm', strtolower($listDirn), $saveOrderlistUrl);
```

Inside Looping data:

```
<tr class="row<?php echo $i % 2; ?>" sortable-group-id="<?php echo $row->category_id; ?>">
```

The particular category data only visible when try to click & drag.Thats works fine.
After changing the ordering,if I check the database, the ordering for the data is incorrect and its interchanged with overall max(ordering).Not for the particular category datas. Kindly help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you should add `getReorderConditions()` method to your `Group` model:

```
/**
 * A protected method to get a set of ordering conditions.
 *
 * @param   object  $table A record object.
 *
 * @return  array   An array of conditions to add to add to ordering queries.
 */
protected function getReorderConditions($table)
{
    $condition = array();
    $condition[] = 'catid = ' . (int) $table->catid;

    return $condition;
}
```

`catid` is the category field in your table.

`getReorderConditions()` method is used in `reorder()` method of `JModelAdmin` class to apply additional conditions to reorder query.